# Router basename is not able to match the URL because it does not start with the basename

Tags: reactjs, react-router

After upgrading to React Router v6, my application stopped working and I failed to find a way to achieve the same behavior with version 6.

This is the version I upgraded to: `react-router-dom` `6.2.1`.

This is the code that worked with the previous version `5.2.0`:

```
<Router basename="/#">
  <Route path="/login">
    <Login />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/">
    <Home />
  </Route>
</Router>

            
<Link to="/login">Login</Link>
```

And I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/#/login`. Now even `http://localhost:3000` doesn't work.

This is the full error I get in the browser console:

*<Router basename="/#"> is not able to match the URL "/" because it does not start with the basename, so the <Router> won't render anything.*

I've read all I can find on StackOverflow, in the Github issues, the migration guide, tried a number of workarounds, but nothing seems to achieve the old behavior. It's like the v6 doesn't respect URL fragments at all.

I need the URL fragments so that when a user refreshes a page or bookmarks a URL, it actually works.

How to make this work with React Router v6?

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/multi-app

Comment: Are you using a `HashRouter`?

Comment: @MarioG8 I've already looked that up before posting. It's a different much simpler case. I want to prefix everything using fragments. The example app does pretty much what the docs say.

Comment: @DrewReese No. I am using `BrowserRouter`.

Comment: Ok, have you tried using a `HashRouter` then? I believe it basically already does what adding `"/#"`  does, for the exact purpose you're asking about. ‍♂️

Comment: I had exactly the same issue, `<HashRouter />` without passing `basename` worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

This is too sad that react documentation does not specify anything regarding basename in react router v6. however, I tried something and it worked. please find below solution. cheers!

```
<HashRouter> 
    <Routes>
        <Route path='/app'> {/* put url base here and nest children routes */}
            <Route path='path1' element={ <Somecomponent1 /> } />
            <Route path='path2' element={ <Somecomponent2 /> } />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/*" element={<Navigate to="/app/path1" />}  /> {/* navigate to default route if no url matched */}
    </Routes>
</HashRouter>
```

Answer (score 6):

You need wrap your Route component inside Routes component. [Link](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route) to docs that explains this. There are also changes in Route component you need to look up.

Anyway, this should work:

```
<Router basename="/#">
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route index path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Routes>
</Router>
```

Comment: link is not working any more