# Host react project in a sub-folder of a domain

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need to host my react project in a sub-folder of a domain. e.g. `mydomain.com/react-project/`

In the project, I am using `react-router` library for routing. I have this `.htaccess` file in the `react-project` folder to make work the router.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /subdirectory
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

For the home page, the project working fine. But for other URLs, the server shows the default apache "not found" page.

I tried to create a `.htaccess` file in the root folder of the server.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /react-project/index.html
```

With this `.htaccess` file, I wanted to redirect  the browser to react projects `index.html` file. But it didn't work.

Comment: Take a look over these [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing) docs to see what you may've missed in configuring for apache.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is because of Client side, Server side routing issue.
I think when you refresh the page it shows 404 not found on server.
You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623117) answer for help. Also use [HashRouter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71660922/13405106) instead of BrowserRouter and add basename={"/subdirectory"} in Routes.